# ¿Como funciona strcmp en PHP?

Tags: php

Quisiera saber como funciona strcmp en PHP, ya que tengo una duda en cuanto al resultado que arroja, se que cuando se compara y son igualas dara como resultado 0, pero en otros casos el resultado varia un poco (1,-1,5,45 etc.), cuales serian algunos ejemplos en el que varien los resultados con una breve explicacion.

```
<?php

    $variable1 = "walter";
    $variable2 = "Alejandro";

    $resultado = strcmp($variable1, $variable2);
    var_dump($resultado);


?>
```

Comment: En la documentación está indicado el significado de cada valor http://php.net/manual/es/function.strcmp.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como bien lo indica la [documentacion](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strcmp.php) de PHP:

> Comparación de string segura a nivel binario

**Que significa esto?**

La comparacion que se realice, tendra en cuenta diferentes elementos que puedan variar de una cadena a la otra, desde un *espacio* hasta una *mayuscula*.

**¿Como podemos evidenciar ello?**

He aqui un ejemplo:

```
<?php

$cadena = "hola mundo";

$cadena_A = "hola";
$cadena_B = "hola mundo";
$cadena_C = "hola mundo cruel";

if(strcmp($cadena_A, $cadena) < 0){
        print "$cadena_A es menor que $cadena\n";
}


if(strcmp($cadena_B, $cadena) == 0){
        print "$cadena_A es igual que $cadena\n";
}

if(strcmp($cadena_C, $cadena) > 0){
        print "$cadena_A es mayor que $cadena\n";
}

?>
```

Si ejecutamos el programa, el resultado sera:

```
hola es menor que hola mundo
hola es igual que hola mundo
hola es mayor que hola mundo
```

**¿Porque nos devolvio ese resultado?**

Como lo indica la [documentacion](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strcmp.php) de PHP:

> Devuelve < 0 si str1 es menor que str2; > 0 si str1 es mayor que str2
>   y 0 si son iguales.

**¿Que quiere decir?**

Se hace una diferencia entre las dos cadenas, indicando un valor, que variara si la una tiene mas o menos texto que la otra cadena contra la que se compara.